# making games in C++ or making games in java?

Tags: java, c++

I'm programming games in java, because i really love java and it's much more easier, but i keep seeing c++ games, c++ engines on the internet. It looks like video game world turning around c++. But still i don't like c++.

I know, there is too many librarys and engines for c++, java has less.

So, i was wacthing videos about GDC and new game engines and the idea of start making games in c++ came my mind but like i said; i dont like c++.

I just wanted to ask should i keed going with java or should i move to c++? and why?

Btw, i'll game developer, it's not just hobby.

Comment: This is too opinionated.  I suggest you do it in C++ because you don't like C++.  Or I suggest you do it in Java because you like Java.  Or choose a scripting language that can interface to a game engine.

Comment: If performance is a concern, you may want to seriously consider C++. Otherwise, use whatever.

Comment: I guess minecraft was written in Java. But if you don't seek for a hobby then what you like and what not is just an excuse

Comment: If you write games in a language you hate, you will hate writing games. Have you looked into the Unity engine?

Comment: Even the world class athletes hate the training they do...

Comment: actually you right JuniorCompressor, i shouldn't write games in language which i don't like

Comment: Make games in Scratch.

Comment: why would i ? it looks bad tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the best thing you can do is ask yourself if you currently feel limited by Java. You mention that there are lots of C++ libraries out there. If you're having trouble finding Java libraries to do the things you're looking to do, but can find plenty of C++ libraries that would have done what you wanted, it would probably be worth switching.

On the other hand, if you're not felling held back by Java, and you're able to get things done, switching to C++ isn't going to be needed. Other people 'seeming' to use C++ isn't a reason for you to leave Java if you like and are comfortable with it.